# Handling large data in VueJs

Tags: vue.js

I currently have large list which holds around 1k+ records and these records are bind to table. The table also consists of input elements like textbox, dropdown which are used to update the list data. The problem now is obviously regarding performance when the list is bind to DOM and it's also sluggish during scrolling. Is there anything that can be improved?, I don't want to use pagination and also can't use virtual-scroll as i have input elements as they would trigger update event. Here's just an example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    bigData: new Array(100000)   
  } 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.5/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Id</td>
    <td>Random Text</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="(item, index) in bigData">
    <td>{{ index }}</td>
    <td><input type="text" v-model="index"><td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: It's hard to imagine a table with **100,000** rows that is design for humans to use. If each row is 1cm high, your user will need to scroll a kilometer of screen space to see it. The answer is the obvious one. Reduce the amount of data and provide an interface where people get a subset of the data they need.

Comment: Have you ever tried Cluster Js Plugin? Maybe this can help you. https://clusterize.js.org/ ... But thats not a good practice when you are in production. Use Pagination Instead.]

Comment: "I don't want to use pagination"... In other words, I don't want to have good UX. Show me how to render the mess nobody will read.

Comment: Well I can fix this with pagination, but the point is client suggested no pagination instead add textbox to filter and first show few records and then when user scroll rest should come up same like facebook news feeds. Facebook has infinity scroll with lazy loading :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, after lots of testing, I came to the conclusion its the best to use pages in combination with filters. (I had 5*100 inputs.)

The problem is that your browser start lagging because the JS and HTMl to parse just gets much.